# How do i split an integer and all the digits produced to create a new number?

Tags: javascript

For instance, if i have the number 4444. I need it to do 4+4+4+4=16.
i want to get the result of 16. I tried changing the number to a string and got the array. But i don't know how to add it after. I searched it up but the other examples were too complicated for my level.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nbnm8he5/

var number = 4444;
var digits = number.toString().split('');
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
 sum += parseInt(digits[i]);
}

alert(sum);

Answer (score 3):

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/kebekib/2/edit?js,console)

```
var n = 4444;

var a = n.toString().split('').map(Number).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
});
```

- Turn number to string
- Split it
- Map over array to return Numbers
- Reduce to get total

or with a loop:

```
var sum = 0;
var string = n.toString();
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  sum = sum + Number(string[i]);
}
```

Comment: can u show me a way that doesnt involve using map and reduce cuz i dont know what that is, something more simpler pls

Comment: jsfiddle.net/nbnm8he5